# how to convert english number to persian in r

Tags: r, arabic, farsi

I have some numbers in English format and I want to convert them to Persian or Arabic format.
For this purpose, I used the following function:

```r
    convert_english_to_farsi<-function(x) {
  persian <- "\u0660\u0661\u0662\u0663\u0664\u0665\u0666\u0667\u0668\u0669\u06F0\u06F1\u06F2\u06F3\u06F4\u06F5\u06F6\u06F7\u06F8\u06F9"
  english <- "\U0030\U0031\U0032\U0033\U0034\U0035\U0036\U0037\U0038\U0039\U0030\U0031\U0032\U0033\U0034\U0035\U0036\U0037\U0038\U0039"
  return(chartr(english,persian, x))
}
```

And when I executed the function to convert numbers to Persian, I got this error:

```r
> convert_english_to_farsi(2345)
[1] "H‎!ë„\001"
```

While I want the Persian numbers to be displayed as follows when I run the function "convert_english_to_farsi"

So i want geting persian number Like the example below:

```r
> convert_english_to_farsi(2345)
[1] "٢٣٤٥"
```

Comment: What is your OS? I am getting the right result in Ubuntu 20.04. `convert_english_to_farsi(1234567890)` returns `[1] "۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰"`.

Comment: My operating system is Windows 10, is it possible that there is an error in the system keyboard settings or I can add Persian language to the R

Comment: Related: [Convert English numbers to Persian for ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593481/convert-english-numbers-to-persian-for-ggplot?rq=1)